# Force Java 6 usage with Java 7 installed

Tags: java, runtime

I am trying to get Java 6 and Java 7 to co-exist on about 8 computers.  Most programs we are using use Java7, but this site: https://oas1.ost.state.ok.us/forms/frmservlet does not work with Java 7.

I have researched a lot based on posts here and outside. It seems that all browsers default to Java7 if it is installed.

I have tried disabling  Java 7 on Internet Explorer, but even the `Java 1.6.0_45` plug-in runs the jre7 version `javaw.exe`.

Firefox shows no plug-in for Java 6 if Java 7 is installed, but if i remove Java7 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you go in the Control Panel of Windows, you will find the Java Control Panel.

Then go in the tab Java and from there you can enable/disable which jre should run applets.

P.S. I have italian OS so maybe the labels are different but you should be able to find the option once you look in the Java Control Panel.